# How do you get the Chrome cast extension to show the media title?

Tags: google-cast

How do I get the media title to display in the cast extension menu?  The extension is showing my application name instead of the `cast.receiver.MediaManager.getMediaInformation().metadata.title` value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `CastReceiverManager.setApplicationState()` in your receiver and pass the title or whatever you see appropriate. Please read through the comments in this G+ [post](https://plus.google.com/113603561173832215383/posts/NYcEkwWDiWu) to get a bit more insight into that.